# autocomplete selected items into div tag

Tags: jquery, html

am binding the selected records of autocomplete box into div as

```
var data = "<div class='close'><table><tr><td rowspan='4' width='50px;'><img src='" + studentItem.Photo + "' Width='48' Height='48'  /></td><td>" + studentItem.Name + " ( <span class='stuId'>" + studentItem.StudentId + "</span> )</td><td align='right' ><div id='close' class='close16'/></td></tr><tr><td><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>" + studentItem.Email + "</td><td>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td><td>" + studentItem.Mobile + "</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>";
            $('#students').css('background-color', '#FFAA55');
            $("#students").append(data);
```

and its binding the datas as

[image]

I want the each record should be in a seperate box, for example look at tag box in our stackoverflow

[image]

i want the result should be like this above.......I even tried to include the div script into a table, but it displays the single record in a whole row, and for the second record it comes to the second row, how can I fix this, can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a css property update:

Set the divs to `display: inline-block`

Comment: i dont understand where I've to use inline, can u give me code sample here...i just set my div script as <div id="students" style="display: inline"></div> still facing the same problem